# Usage of　に、とき, ときに

Tags: particle-に

Are these sentences correct?

> - クリスマス**に**パソコンを買った。
> - クリスマス**のとき**パソコンを買った。
> - クリスマス**のときに**パソコンを買った。

What is the difference when using  **に、とき, ときに**?

Answer (score 0):

- At Christmas, I bought...
- During Christmas, I bought...
- During Christmas time, I bought...

There aren't any significant differences in the English sentences above. **They mean the same thing.** Much the same case for your sentences.  とき is a shortened form of ときに, which is a more explicit and completely unambiguous version of  に.

In your scenario, the temporal use of  に is extremely clear. But there may be other situations where the meaning of に (since it's a particle with a lot of meanings) is a bit ambiguous, and you might want to swap it for ときに **to be extra clear in communication.**

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Sabrina's answer, depending on the context に alone could be interpreted as you bought the laptop *for* Christmas for example.
A general rule to follow is that if you're combining とき with a noun, use 〜のとき and if it's a verb just use 〜とき. However in casual speech this rule is often broken of course.

Some examples:

"In my childhood..." : 「私の子ども**のとき**に...」
"When I ride my bike..." : 「自転車に乗る**とき**に...」

If it's already a period of time you just say に, although Christmas is a noun, one could argue it's also a period of time, and along with being left out pretty often in casual speech I understand the confusion. But for formal use, or just when in doubt, it's safest to go with what Sabrina said and use のとき.

Found a good guide: https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/toki/